# ZINO UI Issue on MVC application - Splitter pane not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am creating a split pane using zino UI. I have downloaded the example code for the split pane and trying to run from my machine with ASP.NET MVC,getting error when I try to run from a ASP.NET MVC Project. But from normal HTML page it is working fine.

Error " SCRIPT438: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'zinoSplitter'"

Demo example:
https://zinoui.com/demos/splitter#default-1

```
<head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.zinoui.com/1.5/themes/silver/zino.core.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.zinoui.com/1.5/themes/silver/zino.splitter.css">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-rsPUGdUPBXgalvIj4YKJrrUlmLXbOb6Cp7cdxn1qeUc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://static.zinoui.com/1.5/compiled/zino.position.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://static.zinoui.com/1.5/compiled/zino.draggable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://static.zinoui.com/1.5/compiled/zino.splitter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://static.zinoui.com/js/front.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="vertical">
    <div class="splitter-north"><div class="splitter-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tristique, est in mollis egestas, odio ipsum rutrum erat, ut tincidunt dui elit non tellus. Phasellus tristique est vel tortor aliquet, sed ullamcorper erat porta. Nam tristique sem felis, eu ornare metus tincidunt non. Nullam eros eros, molestie nec odio eget, bibendum tincidunt leo.</div></div>
    <div id="horizontal">
        <div class="splitter-west"><div class="splitter-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tristique, est in mollis egestas, odio ipsum rutrum erat, ut tincidunt dui elit non tellus. Phasellus tristique est vel tortor aliquet, sed ullamcorper erat porta. Nam tristique sem felis, eu ornare metus tincidunt non. Nullam eros eros, molestie nec odio eget, bibendum tincidunt leo. Fusce eget velit vitae diam rutrum sodales id at magna. Etiam vitae odio nec mi tempor tristique. Donec volutpat neque non tortor blandit, at luctus augue malesuada.</div></div>
        <div class="splitter-center" id="center">
            <div class="splitter-center-north"><div class="splitter-content">Phasellus tristique est vel tortor aliquet, sed ullamcorper erat porta. Nam tristique sem felis, eu ornare metus tincidunt non.</div></div>
            <div class="splitter-center-south"><div class="splitter-content">Nullam eros eros, molestie nec odio eget, bibendum tincidunt leo. Fusce eget velit vitae diam rutrum sodales id at magna.</div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="splitter-east"><div class="splitter-content">Nulla tristique, est in mollis egestas, odio ipsum rutrum erat, ut tincidunt dui elit non tellus. Phasellus tristique est vel tortor aliquet, sed ullamcorper erat porta. Nam tristique sem felis, eu ornare metus tincidunt non. Nullam eros eros, molestie nec odio eget, bibendum tincidunt leo.</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="splitter-south"><div class="splitter-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tristique, est in mollis egestas, odio ipsum rutrum erat, ut tincidunt dui elit non tellus. Phasellus tristique est vel tortor aliquet, sed ullamcorper erat porta. Nam tristique sem felis, eu ornare metus tincidunt non.</div></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#horizontal").zinoSplitter({
            panes: [
                { size: 150, collapsible: true, region: "west" },
                { size: 226, collapsible: false, region: "center" },
                { size: 150, collapsible: true, region: "east" }
            ]
        });
        $("#vertical").zinoSplitter({
            orientation: "vertical",
            panes: [
                { size: 80, collapsible: true, resizable: false, region: "north" },
                { size: 196, collapsible: true, region: "center" },
                { size: 50, collapsible: true, region: "south" }
            ]
        });
        $("#center").zinoSplitter({
            orientation: "vertical",
            panes: [
                { size: 96, region: "north", collapsible: true },
                { size: 96, region: "south", collapsible: true }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #vertical {
        height: 334px;
        width: 534px;
        background-color: #E6E6E6;
    }

    #horizontal,
    #center {
        background-color: #E6E6E6;
    }

    .splitter-north {
        background-color: #D9D9D9;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: solid 1px #aaa;
    }

    .splitter-south,
    .splitter-west,
    .splitter-east,
    .splitter-center-north,
    .splitter-center-south {
        background-color: #E6E6E6;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: solid 1px #aaa;
    }

    .splitter-center {
        background-color: #E6E6E6;
    }

    .splitter-content {
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I registered the js file in Bundleconfig.cs and it worked.